# PHP Regex negation

Tags: php, regex

I have a web bot which extracts some data from a website. The problem is that the html content is sent without line brakes so it's a little bit harder to match certain things so I need to extract everything that is between td tags. Here's a string example:

```
<a class="a" href="javascript:ow(19623507)">**-**-**-***.cstel.net</a>&nbsp; (<b><font color="#3300cc">Used</font></b>)</td><td><a class="a" href="javascript:ow(19623507)">**-**-**-***.cstel.net</a>&nbsp; (<b><font color="#3300cc">Used</font></b>)</td>
```

And my regex so far:

```
<a\s+class="a"\s+href="javascript:ow\((.*?)\)">.+</a>(?!<td>).+</td>
```

But my regex matches the whole line instead of matching all  contents. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste your time on regexes. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and XPath.

```
 DOMDocument::loadHTML($html)->getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `.+` to `.+?` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine where the proper line breaks SHOULD be? If so, it might be easier to first replace those tokens with a proper line break and then use the pattern you have (assuming that pattern works - I haven't tried it).

Your pattern looks VERY specific, but perhaps it works fine for what you are doing.