# How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

How can one parse HTML/XML and extract information from it?

Answer (score 2010, accepted):

### Native XML Extensions

I prefer using one of the [native XML extensions](https://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) since they come bundled with PHP, are usually faster than all the 3rd party libs and give me all the control I need over the markup.

#### [DOM](https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

> The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents through the DOM API with PHP 5. It is an implementation of the W3C's Document Object Model Core Level 3, a platform- and language-neutral interface that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure and style of documents.

DOM is capable of parsing and modifying real world (broken) HTML and it can do [XPath queries](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html). It is based on [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).

It takes some time to get productive with DOM, but that time is well worth it IMO. Since DOM is a language-agnostic interface, you'll find implementations in many languages, so if you need to change your programming language, chances are you will already know how to use that language's DOM API then.

How to use the DOM extension has been [covered extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+HTML+%5BPHP%5D&submit=search) on StackOverflow, so if you choose to use it, you can be sure most of the issues you run into can be solved by searching/browsing Stack Overflow.

A [basic usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3820783) and a [general conceptual overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983721) are available in other answers.

#### [XMLReader](https://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)

> The XMLReader extension is an XML pull parser. The reader acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way.

XMLReader, like DOM, is based on libxml. I am not aware of how to trigger the HTML Parser Module, so chances are using XMLReader for parsing broken HTML might be less robust than using DOM where you can explicitly tell it to use libxml's HTML Parser Module.

A [basic usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299140) is available in another answer.

#### [XML Parser](https://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

> This extension lets you create XML parsers and then define handlers for different XML events. Each XML parser also has a few parameters you can adjust.

The XML Parser library is also based on libxml, and implements a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) style XML push parser. It may be a better choice for memory management than DOM or SimpleXML, but will be more difficult to work with than the pull parser implemented by XMLReader.

#### [SimpleXml](https://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

> The SimpleXML extension provides a very simple and easily usable toolset to convert XML to an object that can be processed with normal property selectors and array iterators.

SimpleXML is an option when you know the HTML is valid XHTML. If you need to parse broken HTML, don't even consider SimpleXml because it will choke.

A [basic usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4906459) is available, and there are [lots of additional examples in the PHP Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

---

### 3rd Party Libraries (libxml based)

If you prefer to use a 3rd-party lib, I'd suggest using a lib that actually uses [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)/[libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) underneath instead of string parsing.

#### [FluentDom](https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM)

> FluentDOM provides a jQuery-like fluent XML interface for the DOMDocument in PHP. Selectors are written in XPath or CSS (using a CSS to XPath converter). Current versions extend the DOM implementing standard interfaces and add features from the DOM Living Standard. FluentDOM can load formats like JSON, CSV, JsonML, RabbitFish and others. Can be installed via Composer.

#### [HtmlPageDom](https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom)

> `Wa72\HtmlPageDom` is a PHP library for easy manipulation of HTML
> documents using DOM. It requires [DomCrawler from Symfony2
> components](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler) for traversing
> the DOM tree and extends it by adding methods for manipulating the
> DOM tree of HTML documents.

#### [phpQuery](https://github.com/electrolinux/phpquery)

> phpQuery is a server-side, chainable, CSS3 selector driven Document Object Model (DOM) API based on jQuery JavaScript Library.
> The library is written in PHP5 and provides additional Command Line Interface (CLI).

This is described as "abandonware and buggy: use at your own risk" but does appear to be minimally maintained.

#### [laminas-dom](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-dom/)

> The Laminas\Dom component (formerly Zend_DOM) provides tools for working with DOM documents and structures. Currently, we offer `Laminas\Dom\Query`, which provides a unified interface for querying DOM documents utilizing both XPath and CSS selectors.
>
> This package is considered feature-complete, and is now in security-only maintenance mode.

#### [fDOMDocument](http://github.com/theseer/fDOMDocument)

> fDOMDocument extends the standard DOM to use exceptions at all occasions of errors instead of PHP warnings or notices. They also add various custom methods and shortcuts for convenience and to simplify the usage of DOM.

#### [sabre/xml](http://sabre.io/xml/)

> sabre/xml is a library that wraps and extends the XMLReader and XMLWriter classes to create a simple "xml to object/array" mapping system and design pattern. Writing and reading XML is single-pass and can therefore be fast and require low memory on large xml files.

#### [FluidXML](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml)

> FluidXML is a PHP library for manipulating XML with a concise and fluent API.
> It leverages XPath and the fluent programming pattern to be fun and effective.

---

### 3rd-Party (not libxml-based)

The benefit of building upon DOM/libxml is that you get good performance out of the box because you are based on a native extension. However, not all 3rd-party libs go down this route. Some of them listed below

#### [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html)

> - An HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ lets you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
> - Require PHP 5+.
> - Supports invalid HTML.
> - Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
> - Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

I generally do not recommend this parser. The codebase is horrible and the parser itself is rather slow and memory hungry. Not all jQuery Selectors (such as [child selectors](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)) are possible. Any of the libxml based libraries should outperform this easily.

#### [PHP Html Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser)

> PHPHtmlParser is a simple, flexible, html parser which allows you to select tags using any css selector, like jQuery. The goal is to assiste in the development of tools which require a quick, easy way to scrape html, whether it's valid or not! This project was original supported by sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser but the support seems to have stopped so this project is my adaptation of his previous work.

Again, I would not recommend this parser. It is rather slow with high CPU usage. There is also no function to clear memory of created DOM objects. These problems scale particularly with nested loops. The documentation itself is inaccurate and misspelled, with no responses to fixes since 14 Apr 16.

---

### HTML 5

You can use the above for parsing HTML5, but [there can be quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4029341) due to the markup HTML5 allows. So for HTML5 you may want to consider using a dedicated parser. Note that these are written in PHP, so suffer from slower performance and increased memory usage compared to a compiled extension in a lower-level language.

#### [HTML5DomDocument](https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php/)

> HTML5DOMDocument extends the native DOMDocument library. It fixes some bugs and adds some new functionality.
>
> - Preserves html entities (DOMDocument does not)
> - Preserves void tags (DOMDocument does not)
> - Allows inserting HTML code that moves the correct parts to their proper places (head elements are inserted in the head, body elements in the body)
> - Allows querying the DOM with CSS selectors (currently available: `*`, `tagname`, `tagname#id`, `#id`, `tagname.classname`, `.classname`, `tagname.classname.classname2`, `.classname.classname2`, `tagname[attribute-selector]`, `[attribute-selector]`, `div, p`, `div p`, `div > p`, `div + p`, and `p ~ ul`.)
> - Adds support for element->classList.
> - Adds support for element->innerHTML.
> - Adds support for element->outerHTML.

#### [HTML5](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php)

> HTML5 is a standards-compliant HTML5 parser and writer written entirely in PHP. It is stable and used in many production websites, and has well over five million downloads.
>
> HTML5 provides the following features.

> - An HTML5 serializer
> - Support for PHP namespaces
> - Composer support
> - Event-based (SAX-like) parser
> - A DOM tree builder
> - Interoperability with QueryPath
> - Runs on PHP 5.3.0 or newer

---

### Regular Expressions

Last and **least recommended**, you can extract data from HTML with [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regular%20expression%20tutorials). In general using Regular Expressions on HTML is discouraged.

Most of the snippets you will find on the web to match markup are brittle. In most cases they are only working for a very particular piece of HTML. Tiny markup changes, like adding whitespace somewhere, or adding, or changing attributes in a tag, can make the RegEx fails when it's not properly written. You should know what you are doing before using RegEx on HTML.

HTML parsers already know the syntactical rules of HTML. Regular expressions have to be taught for each new RegEx you write. RegEx are fine in some cases, but it really depends on your use-case.

You [can write more reliable parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491), but writing a *complete and reliable* custom parser with regular expressions is a waste of time when the aforementioned libraries already exist and do a much better job on this.

Also see [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

---

### Books

If you want to spend some money, have a look at

- [PHP Architect's Guide to Webscraping with PHP](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-web-scraping-with-php)

I am not affiliated with PHP Architect or the authors.

Comment: @Naveed that depends on your needs. I have no need for CSS Selector queries, which is why I use DOM with XPath exclusively. phpQuery aims to be a jQuery port. Zend_Dom is lightweight. You really have to check them out to see which one you like best.

Comment: s/HTML5/HTML/g. The syntactical constructs HTML5 allows are mostly already allowed by any previous HTML version.

Comment: @Ms2ger Mostly, but not completely. Like already pointed out above, you can use the libxml based parsers but there is special cases where those will choke. If you need maximum compatibility you are better off with a dedicated parser. I prefer to keep the distinction.

Comment: Your point for not using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser seems moot.

Comment: As of Mar 29, 2012, DOM does not support html5, XMLReader does not support HTML and last commit on html5lib for PHP is on Sep 2009. What to use to parse HTML5, HTML4 and XHTML?

Comment: @Shiplu answer above lists all the options I know. DOM can parse anything that has a Schema or a DTD. HTML5 doesnt (officially).

Comment: Just to add some experience: I've used some of them, and am now always recommending ganon, as in most (of my) cases it's actually way faster than even the native versions because of how it works, and also works very well with invalid/damaged/incomplete documents (which none of the others I know of can handle at all). Sometimes it's also worth it to just regress to writing your own or use regex, but thats ONLY if you have very special and simple requirements (e.g. must only support 2 tags in a fixed format)

Comment: @Jimmy it doesn't include anything about cURL because cURL is not a tool to parse and process HTML/XML with. cURL is a client for various network protocols. For instance, you can fetch websites with it. Most of the libraries above have ways to load remote URLs directly, so you don't need cURL at all, for instance DOM has `loadHTMLFile()`.

Comment: Regarding 3rd Party Libraries (libxml based) I've found that:
- QueryPath doesn't work for me as it choked on malformed HTML (even using htmlqp())
- phpQuery is a little harder to approach
Besides
- html5lib has a very active python part but the php port seems of low maintenance

If you're looking for a quick-and-dirty solution I can recommend https://github.com/hkk12369/php-html-parser

Comment: @Gordon I suggest adding Symfony's "CSSSelector" component for adding "CSS selector" based DOM crawling to DOMDocument ( as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/24550527#24550527 ) and Symfony's "DOMCrawler" component, depending on whether you want low level access to the DOM or a more high level approach.

Comment: Remember? [You cannot parse (X)HTML using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/)! (It struck me the day I read it I now believe mentioning regex alongside of HTML is a sin.)

Comment: @Nasha I deliberately excluded the infamous Zalgo rant from the list above because it's not too helpful on it's own and lead to quite some cargo cult since it was written. People were slapped down with that link no matter how appropriate a regex would have been as a solution. For a more balanced opinion, please see the link I *did* include instead and go through the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245008/php-regex-simple-regex-for-bbcode-s-or-strike-fails-to-work

Comment: Ultimate Web Scraper Toolkit's TagFilter class is distinctly missing from this list.  I used Simple HTML DOM for many years because it was the most reliably consistent thing I could find.  TagFilter is something I wrote initially because I needed to be able to cleanly process Word HTML but then I realized I was in reach of replacing both Simple HTML DOM and HTMLPurifier with something far more flexible, scalable (to handle multi-MB HTML files without memory leaks), and much faster.  In the case of the 1MB+ HTMLPurifier library, it's much smaller and self-contained.  It's also maintained.

Comment: @Gordon, thank  you for the fantastically excellent answer. It's 10 years old now, I wouldn't suppose you could do a refresh for 2021?

Comment: @scott8035 Thanks. I have no idea about current XML libs. I'd probably still use the native DOM extension

Answer (score 346):

Try [**Simple HTML DOM Parser**](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/).

- A HTML DOM parser written in PHP 5+ that lets you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
- Require PHP 5+.
- Supports invalid HTML.
- Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
- Extract contents from HTML in a single line.
- [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/)

Note: as the name suggests, it can be useful for simple tasks. It uses regular expressions instead of an HTML parser, so will be considerably slower for more complex tasks. The bulk of its codebase was written in 2008, with only small improvements made since then. It does not follow modern PHP coding standards and would be challenging to incorporate into a modern PSR-compliant project.

### [Examples:](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)

#### How to get HTML elements:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

#### How to modify HTML elements:

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html;
```

#### Extract content from HTML:

```
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

#### Scraping Slashdot:

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://slashdot.org/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

Comment: Well firstly there's things I need to prepare for such as bad DOM's, Invlid code, also js analysing against DNSBL engine, this will also be used to look out for malicious sites / content, also the as i have built my site around a framework i have built it needs to be clean, readable, and well structured. SimpleDim is great but the code is slightly messy

Comment: as I said, I have used simple DOM many times before and its Excellent, just looking for a system with cleaner code that's highly extendible, OO(P|D) Wise etc

Comment: @Robert you might also want to check out http://htmlpurifier.org/ for the security related things.

Comment: He's got one valid point: simpleHTMLDOM is hard to extend, unless you use decorator pattern, which I find unwieldy. I've found myself *shudder* just making changes to the underlying class(es) themselves.

Comment: What I did was run my html through tidy before sending it to SimpleDOM.

Comment: I'm using this currently, running it as part of a project to process a few hundred urls. It's becoming very slow and regular timeouts persist. It is a great beginners script and intuitively simple to learn, but just too basic for more advanced projects.

Answer (score 251):

Just use [DOMDocument->loadHTML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and be done with it. libxml's HTML parsing algorithm is quite good and fast, and contrary to popular belief, does not choke on malformed HTML.

Comment: True. And it works with PHP's built-in XPath and XSLTProcessor classes, which are great for extracting content.

Comment: For really mangled HTML, you can always run it through htmltidy before handing it off to DOM. Whenever I need to scrape data from HTML, I always use DOM, or at least simplexml.

Comment: Another thing with loading malformed HTML i that it might be wise to call libxml_use_internal_errors(true) to prevent warnings that will stop parsing.

Comment: I have used DOMDocument to parse about 1000 html sources (in various languages encoded with different charsets) without any issues. You might run into encoding issues with this, but they aren't insurmountable. You need to know 3 things: 1) loadHTML uses meta tag's charset to determine encoding 2) #2 can lead to incorrect encoding detection if the html content doesn't include this information 3) bad UTF-8 characters can trip the parser. In such cases, use a combination of mb_detect_encoding() and Simplepie RSS Parser's encoding / converting / stripping bad UTF-8 characters code for workarounds.

Comment: Yes, but DOMDocument does not support CSS and XPATH queries, just getElementById or getElementsByTagName?

Comment: My problem with loadHTML is the extra nodes it inserts, which are presumably there to "fix" the HTML but aren't actually required by the DOM spec. As such, the result of a loadHTML call is ill defined. Would have been much better to have this sort of thing happen on saveHTML.

Comment: DOM does actually support XPath, take a look at [DOMXPath](http://php.net/domxpath).

Comment: My preference goes to using DOMDocument->loadHTML() in combination with Symfony's "CSSSelector" component, which translates CSS Selectors to XPath selectors. It's still very low level and makes DOM a lot easier to use for those with lots of experience in frontend programming ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/24550527#24550527 for more details )

Answer (score 155):

**Why you shouldn't and *when you should* use regular expressions?**

First off, a common misnomer: Regexps are not for *"**parsing**"* HTML. Regexes can however *"**extract**"* data. Extracting is what they're made for. The major drawback of regex HTML extraction over proper SGML toolkits or baseline XML parsers are their syntactic effort and varying reliability.

Consider that making a somewhat dependable HTML extraction regex:

```
<a\s+class="?playbutton\d?[^>]+id="(\d+)".+?    <a\s+class="[\w\s]*title
[\w\s]*"[^>]+href="(http://[^">]+)"[^>]*>([^<>]+)</a>.+?
```

is way less readable than a simple phpQuery or QueryPath equivalent:

```
$div->find(".stationcool a")->attr("title");
```

There are however specific use cases where they can help.

- Many DOM traversal frontends don't reveal HTML comments `<!--`, which however are sometimes the more useful anchors for extraction. In particular pseudo-HTML variations `<$var>` or SGML residues are easy to tame with regexps.
- Oftentimes regular expressions can save post-processing. However HTML entities often require manual caretaking.
- And lastly, for e*xtremely simple tasks* like extracting <img src= urls, they are in fact a probable tool. The speed advantage over SGML/XML parsers mostly just comes to play for these very basic extraction procedures.

It's sometimes even advisable to pre-extract a snippet of HTML using regular expressions `/<!--CONTENT-->(.+?)<!--END-->/` and process the remainder using the simpler HTML parser frontends.

**Note:** I actually have this [app](http://fossil.include-once.org/streamtuner2/), where I employ XML parsing and regular expressions alternatively. Just last week the PyQuery parsing broke, and the regex still worked. Yes weird, and I can't explain it myself. But so it happened.
So please don't vote real-world considerations down, just because it doesn't match the regex=evil meme. **But let's also not vote this up too much. It's just a sidenote for this topic.**

Comment: [`DOMComment`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domcomment.php) can read comments, so no reason to use Regex for that.

Comment: Neither SGML toolkits or XML parsers are suitable for parsing real world HTML. For that, only a dedicated HTML parser is appropriate.

Comment: @Alohci [`DOM`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) uses [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) and [libxml has a separate HTML parser](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) module which will be used when loading HTML with [`loadHTML()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) so it can very much load "real-world" (read broken) HTML.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks. HTML parsers and XML parsers are still different things though, even if they're packaged in the same library. And they're both different from DOM implementations.

Comment: Well, just a comment about your "real-world consideration" standpoint.  Sure, there ARE useful situations for Regex when parsing HTML.  And there are also useful situations for using GOTO.  And there are useful situations for variable-variables.  So no particular implementation is definitively code-rot for using it.  But it is a VERY strong warning sign.  And the average developer isn't likely to be nuanced enough to tell the difference.  So as a general rule, Regex GOTO and Variable-Variables are all evil.  There are non-evil uses, but those are the exceptions (and rare at that)... (IMHO)

Comment: @mario: Actually, HTML *can* be ‘properly’ parsed using regexes, although usually it takes several of them to do a fair job a tit. It’s just a royal pain in the general case. In specific cases with well-defined input, it verges on trivial.  Those are the cases that people *should* be using regexes on. Big old hungry heavy parsers are really what you need for general cases, though it isn’t always clear to the casual user where to draw that line.  Whichever code is simpler and easier, wins.

Comment: `Most XML parsers cannot see HTML document comments` I'm not sure which parser you are using, but *my* parser can "read" comments. -1

Answer (score 137):

### Note, this answer recommends libraries that have now been abandoned for 10+ years.

[phpQuery](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery) and [QueryPath](https://github.com/technosophos/querypath) are extremely similar in replicating the fluent jQuery API. That's also why they're two of the easiest approaches to *properly* parse HTML in PHP.

**Examples for QueryPath**

Basically you first create a queryable DOM tree from an HTML string:

```
 $qp = qp("<html><body><h1>title</h1>..."); // or give filename or URL
```

The resulting object contains a complete tree representation of the HTML document. It can be traversed using DOM methods. But the common approach is to use CSS selectors like in jQuery:

```
 $qp->find("div.classname")->children()->...;

 foreach ($qp->find("p img") as $img) {
     print qp($img)->attr("src");
 }
```

Mostly you want to use simple `#id` and `.class` or `DIV` tag selectors for `->find()`. But you can also use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) statements, which sometimes are faster. Also typical jQuery methods like `->children()` and `->text()` and particularly `->attr()` simplify extracting the right HTML snippets. (And already have their SGML entities decoded.)

```
 $qp->xpath("//div/p[1]");  // get first paragraph in a div
```

QueryPath also allows injecting new tags into the stream (`->append`), and later output and prettify an updated document (`->writeHTML`). It can not only parse malformed HTML, but also various XML dialects (with namespaces), and even extract data from HTML microformats (XFN, vCard).

```
 $qp->find("a[target=_blank]")->toggleClass("usability-blunder");
```

.

**phpQuery or QueryPath?**

Generally QueryPath is better suited for manipulation of documents. While phpQuery also implements some pseudo AJAX methods (just HTTP requests) to more closely resemble jQuery. It is said that phpQuery is often faster than QueryPath (because of fewer overall features).

For further information on the differences see [this comparison on the wayback machine from tagbyte.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20101230230134/http://www.tagbytag.org/articles/phpquery-vs-querypath). (Original source went missing, so here's an internet archive link. Yes, you can still locate missing pages, people.)

**Advantages**

- Simplicity and Reliability
- Simple to use alternatives `->find("a img, a object, div a")`
- Proper data unescaping (in comparison to regular expression grepping)

Answer (score 92):

Simple HTML DOM is a great open-source parser:

[simplehtmldom.sourceforge](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

It treats DOM elements in an object-oriented way, and the new iteration has a lot of coverage for non-compliant code. There are also some great functions like you'd see in JavaScript, such as the "find" function, which will return all instances of elements of that tag name.

I've used this in a number of tools, testing it on many different types of web pages, and I think it works great.

Answer (score 63):

One general approach I haven't seen mentioned here is to run HTML through [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), which can be set to spit out guaranteed-valid XHTML. Then you can use any old XML library on it.

But to your specific problem, you should take a look at this project: http://fivefilters.org/content-only/ -- it's a modified version of the [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/2009/03/02/readability/) algorithm, which is designed to extract just the textual content (not headers and footers) from a page.

Answer (score 58):

For 1a and 2: I would vote for the new Symfony Componet class DOMCrawler ( [DomCrawler](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/) ).
This class allows queries similar to CSS Selectors. Take a look at this presentation for real-world examples: [news-of-the-symfony2-world](http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/news-of-the-symfony2-world).

The component is designed to work standalone and can be used without Symfony.

The only drawback is that it will only work with PHP 5.3 or newer.

Comment: jquery-like css queries is well said, because there are some things that are missing in w3c documentation, but are present as extra features in jquery.

Answer (score 56):

This is commonly referred to as **screen scraping**, by the way. The library I have used for this is [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

Comment: Not strictly true (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_scraping#Screen_scraping). The clue is in "screen"; in the case described, there's no screen involved. Although, admittedly, the term has suffered an awful lot of recent misuse.

Comment: Im not screen scraping, the content that will be parsed will be authorized by the content supplier under my agreement.

Answer (score 44):

We have created quite a few crawlers for our needs before. At the end of the day, it is usually simple regular expressions that do the thing best. While libraries listed above are good for the reason they are created, if you know what you are looking for, regular expressions is a safer way to go, as you can handle also non-valid [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)/[XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) structures, which would fail, if loaded via most of the parsers.

Answer (score 42):

I recommend [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

It really has nice features, like:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 37):

This sounds like a good task description of W3C [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) technology. It's easy to express queries like "return all `href` attributes in `img` tags that are nested in `<foo><bar><baz> elements`." Not being a PHP buff, I can't tell you in what form XPath may be available. If you can call an external program to process the HTML file you should be able to use a command line version of XPath.
For a quick intro, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath.

Answer (score 31):

Third party alternatives to SimpleHtmlDom that use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org/).

Comment: If you already copy my comments, at least link them properly ;) That should be: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: Good answers are a great source. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606792/best-way-to-parse-an-invalid-html-in-php

Answer (score 27):

Yes you can use simple_html_dom for the purpose. However I have worked quite a lot with the simple_html_dom, particularly for web scraping and have found it to be too vulnerable. It does the basic job but I won't recommend it anyways.

I have never used curl for the purpose but what I have learned is that curl can do the job much more efficiently and is much more solid.

Kindly check out this link:[scraping-websites-with-curl](http://spyderwebtech.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/scraping-websites-with-curl/)

Comment: curl can *get* the file, but it won't parse HTML for you.  That's the hard part.

Answer (score 25):

[Advanced Html Dom](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) is a simple HTML [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) replacement that offers the same interface, but it's DOM-based which means none of the associated memory issues occur.

It also has full CSS support, including [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) extensions.

Comment: I've got good results from Advanced Html Dom, and I think it should be on the list in the accepted answer. An important thing to know though for anyone relying on its "The goal of this project is to be a DOM-based drop-in replacement for PHP's simple html dom library ... If you use file/str_get_html then you don't need to change anything." https://archive.is/QtSuj#selection-933.34-933.100 is that you may need to make changes to your code to accommodate some incompatibilities. I've noted four known to me in the project's github issues. https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom/issues

Answer (score 24):

*QueryPath* is good, but be careful of "tracking state" cause if you didn't realise what it means, it can mean you waste a lot of debugging time trying to find out what happened and why the code doesn't work.

What it means is that each call on the result set modifies the result set in the object, it's not chainable like in jquery where each link is a new set, you have a single set which is the results from your query and each function call modifies that single set.

in order to get jquery-like behaviour, you need to branch before you do a filter/modify like operation, that means it'll mirror what happens in jquery much more closely.

```
$results = qp("div p");
$forename = $results->find("input[name='forename']");
```

`$results` now contains the result set for `input[name='forename']` NOT the original query `"div p"` this tripped me up a lot, what I found was that *QueryPath* tracks the filters and finds and everything which modifies your results and stores them in the object.  you need to do this instead

```
$forename = $results->branch()->find("input[name='forname']")
```

then `$results` won't be modified and you can reuse the result set again and again, perhaps somebody with much more knowledge can clear this up a bit, but it's basically like this from what I've found.

Answer (score 22):

For [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), html5 lib has been abandoned for years now. The only HTML5 library I can find with a recent update and maintenance records is [html5-php](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/releases/1.0.0-beta1) which was just brought to beta 1.0 a little over a week ago.

Answer (score 21):

I created a library named [**PHPPowertools/DOM-Query**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query), which allows you to crawl HTML5 and XML documents just like you do with jQuery.

Under the hood, it uses [**symfony/DomCrawler**](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler) for conversion of CSS selectors to [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) selectors. It always uses the same DomDocument, even when passing one object to another, to ensure decent performance.

---

#### Example use :

```
namespace PowerTools;

// Get file content
$htmlcode = file_get_contents('https://github.com');

// Define your DOMCrawler based on file string
$H = new DOM_Query($htmlcode);

// Define your DOMCrawler based on an existing DOM_Query instance
$H = new DOM_Query($H->select('body'));

// Passing a string (CSS selector)
$s = $H->select('div.foo');

// Passing an element object (DOM Element)
$s = $H->select($documentBody);

// Passing a DOM Query object
$s = $H->select( $H->select('p + p'));

// Select the body tag
$body = $H->select('body');

// Combine different classes as one selector to get all site blocks
$siteblocks = $body->select('.site-header, .masthead, .site-body, .site-footer');

// Nest your methods just like you would with jQuery
$siteblocks->select('button')->add('span')->addClass('icon icon-printer');

// Use a lambda function to set the text of all site blocks
$siteblocks->text(function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class');
});

// Append the following HTML to all site blocks
$siteblocks->append('<div class="site-center"></div>');

// Use a descendant selector to select the site's footer
$sitefooter = $body->select('.site-footer > .site-center');

// Set some attributes for the site's footer
$sitefooter->attr(array('id' => 'aweeesome', 'data-val' => 'see'));

// Use a lambda function to set the attributes of all site blocks
$siteblocks->attr('data-val', function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class') . " - photo by Kelly Clark";
});

// Select the parent of the site's footer
$sitefooterparent = $sitefooter->parent();

// Remove the class of all i-tags within the site's footer's parent
$sitefooterparent->select('i')->removeAttr('class');

// Wrap the site's footer within two nex selectors
$sitefooter->wrap('<section><div class="footer-wrapper"></div></section>');

[...]
```

---

#### Supported methods :

- [x] [$](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) *(1)*
- [x] [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)
- [x] [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)
- [x] [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
- [x] [$selection.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
- [x] [$selection.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [x] [$selection.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [x] [$selection.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [x] [$selection.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [x] [$selection.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [x] [$selection.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [x] [$selection.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [x] [$selection.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [x] [$selection.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [x] [$selection.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [x] [$selection.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [x] [$selection.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) *(2)*
- [x] [$selection.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [x] [$selection.first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [x] [$selection.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [x] [$selection.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
- [x] [$selection.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)
- [x] [$selection.last](http://api.jquery.com/last/)
- [x] [$selection.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [x] [$selection.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [x] [$selection.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [x] [$selection.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [x] [$selection.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [x] [$selection.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [x] [$selection.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

---

1. *Renamed 'select', for obvious reasons*
2. *Renamed 'void', since 'empty' is a reserved word in PHP*

---

#### NOTE :

*The library also includes its own zero-configuration autoloader for PSR-0 compatible libraries. The example included should work out of the box without any additional configuration. Alternatively, you can use it with composer.*

Comment: Looks like the right tool for the job but is not loading for me in PHP 5.6.23 in Worpress. Any additional directions on how to include it correctly?. Included it with:

 
define("BASE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("LIBRARY_PATH", BASE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib/vendor');
require LIBRARY_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Loader.php';
Loader::init(array(LIBRARY_PATH, USER_PATH)); 

in functions.php

Answer (score 18):

You could try using something like [HTML Tidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy) to cleanup any "broken" HTML and convert the HTML to XHTML, which you can then parse with a XML parser.

Answer (score 18):

Another option you can try is [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/). It's inspired by jQuery, but on the server in PHP and used in [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal).

Answer (score 18):

I have written a general purpose XML parser that can easily handle GB files. It's based on XMLReader and it's very easy to use:

```
$source = new XmlExtractor("path/to/tag", "/path/to/file.xml");
foreach ($source as $tag) {
    echo $tag->field1;
    echo $tag->field2->subfield1;
}
```

Here's the github repo: [XmlExtractor](https://github.com/pwarelis/XmlExtractor)

Answer (score 14):

[`XML_HTMLSax`](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_HTMLSax) is rather stable - even if it's not maintained any more. Another option could be to pipe you HTML through [Html Tidy](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) and then parse it with standard XML tools.

Answer (score 14):

There are many ways to process HTML/XML DOM of which most have already been mentioned. Hence, I won't make any attempt to list those myself.

I merely want to add that I personally prefer using the DOM extension and why :

- iit makes optimal use of the performance advantage of the underlying C code
- it's OO PHP (and allows me to subclass it)
- it's rather low level (which allows me to use it as a non-bloated foundation for more advanced behavior)
- it provides access to every part of the DOM (unlike eg. SimpleXml, which ignores some of the lesser known XML features)
- it has a syntax used for DOM crawling that's similar to the syntax used in native Javascript.

And while I miss the ability to use CSS selectors for `DOMDocument`, there is a rather simple and convenient way to add this feature: subclassing the `DOMDocument` and adding JS-like `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` methods to your subclass.

For parsing the selectors, I recommend using the very minimalistic [CssSelector component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) from the [Symfony framework](http://symfony.com/). This component just translates CSS selectors to XPath selectors, which can then be fed into a `DOMXpath` to retrieve the corresponding Nodelist.

You can then use this (still very low level) subclass as a foundation for more high level classes, intended to eg. parse very specific types of XML or add more jQuery-like behavior.

The code below comes straight out my [DOM-Query library](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query) and uses the technique I described.

For HTML parsing :

```
namespace PowerTools;

use \Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector as CssSelector;

class DOM_Document extends \DOMDocument {
    public function __construct($data = false, $doctype = 'html', $encoding = 'UTF-8', $version = '1.0') {
        parent::__construct($version, $encoding);
        if ($doctype && $doctype === 'html') {
            @$this->loadHTML($data);
        } else {
            @$this->loadXML($data);
        }
    }

    public function querySelectorAll($selector, $contextnode = null) {
        if (isset($this->doctype->name) && $this->doctype->name == 'html') {
            CssSelector::enableHtmlExtension();
        } else {
            CssSelector::disableHtmlExtension();
        }
        $xpath = new \DOMXpath($this);
        return $xpath->query(CssSelector::toXPath($selector, 'descendant::'), $contextnode);
    }

    [...]

    public function loadHTMLFile($filename, $options = 0) {
        $this->loadHTML(file_get_contents($filename), $options);
    }

    public function loadHTML($source, $options = 0) {
        if ($source && $source != '') {
            $data = trim($source);
            $html5 = new HTML5(array('targetDocument' => $this, 'disableHtmlNsInDom' => true));
            $data_start = mb_substr($data, 0, 10);
            if (strpos($data_start, '<!DOCTYPE ') === 0 || strpos($data_start, '<html>') === 0) {
                $html5->loadHTML($data);
            } else {
                @$this->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="' . $encoding . '" /></head><body></body></html>');
                $t = $html5->loadHTMLFragment($data);
                $docbody = $this->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
                while ($t->hasChildNodes()) {
                    $docbody->appendChild($t->firstChild);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

See also [Parsing XML documents with CSS selectors](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/42/parsing-xml-documents-with-css-selectors) by Symfony's creator Fabien Potencier on his decision to create the CssSelector component for Symfony and how to use it.

Answer (score 12):

The [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) framework has bundles which can parse the HTML, and you can use CSS style to select the [DOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) instead of using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Answer (score 12):

With [**FluidXML**](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml) you can query and iterate XML using **XPath** and **CSS Selectors**.

```
$doc = fluidxml('<html>...</html>');

$title = $doc->query('//head/title')[0]->nodeValue;

$doc->query('//body/p', 'div.active', '#bgId')
        ->each(function($i, $node) {
            // $node is a DOMNode.
            $tag   = $node->nodeName;
            $text  = $node->nodeValue;
            $class = $node->getAttribute('class');
        });
```

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml

Answer (score 10):

JSON and array from XML in three lines:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Ta da!

Answer (score 10):

There are several reasons to not parse HTML by regular expression. But, if you have total control of what HTML will be generated, then you can do with simple regular expression.

Above it's a function that parses HTML by regular expression. Note that this function is very sensitive and demands that the HTML obey certain rules, but it works very well in many scenarios. If you want a simple parser, and don't want to install libraries, give this a shot:

```
function array_combine_($keys, $values) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
        $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
    }
    array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;'));

    return $result;
}

function extract_data($str) {
    return (is_array($str))
        ? array_map('extract_data', $str)
        : ((!preg_match_all('#<([A-Za-z0-9_]*)[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>#s', $str, $matches))
            ? $str
            : array_map(('extract_data'), array_combine_($matches[1], $matches[2])));
}

print_r(extract_data(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/")));
```

Answer (score 5):

I've created a library called HTML5DOMDocument that is freely available at https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php

It supports query selectors too that I think will be extremely helpful in your case. Here is some example code:

```
$dom = new IvoPetkov\HTML5DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello</h1><div class="content">This is some text</div></body></html>');
echo $dom->querySelector('h1')->innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

The best method for parse xml:

```
$xml='http://www.example.com/rss.xml';
$rss = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {
  $i++;
  echo $title=$feedItem->title;
  echo '<br>';
  echo $link=$feedItem->link;
  echo '<br>';
  if($feedItem->description !='') {
    $des=$feedItem->description;
  } else {
    $des='';
  }
  echo $des;
  echo '<br>';
  if($i>5) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### There are many ways:

**In General:**

- **Native XML Extensions:** they come bundled with PHP, are usually faster than all the 3rd party libs, and give me all the control you need over the markup.
- **DOM:** DOM is capable of parsing and modifying real-world (broken) HTML and it can do XPath queries. It is based on libxml.
- **XML Reader:** XMLReader, like DOM, is based on libxml. The XMLReader extension is an XML pull parser. The reader acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way
- **XML Parser:** This extension lets you create XML parsers and then define handlers for different XML events. Each XML parser also has a few parameters you can adjust. It implements a SAX style XML push parser.
- **Simple XML:** The SimpleXML extension provides a very simple and easily usable toolset to convert XML to an object that can be processed with normal property selectors and array iterators.

**3rd Party Libraries [ libxml based ]:**

- **FluentDom - Repo:** FluentDOM provides a jQuery-like fluent XML interface for the DOMDocument in PHP. It can load formats like JSON, CSV, JsonML, RabbitFish and others. Can be installed via Composer.
- **HtmlPageDom:** is a PHP library for easy manipulation of HTML documents using It requires DomCrawler from Symfony2 components for traversing the DOM tree and extends it by adding methods for manipulating the DOM tree of HTML documents.
- **ZendDOM:** Zend_Dom provides tools for working with DOM documents and structures. Currently, they offer Zend_Dom_Query, which provides a unified interface for querying DOM documents utilizing both XPath and CSS selectors.
- **QueryPath:** QueryPath is a PHP library for manipulating XML and HTML. It is designed to work not only with local files but also with web services and database resources. It implements much of the jQuery interface (including CSS-style selectors), but it is heavily tuned for server-side use. Can be installed via Composer.
- **fDOM Document:** fDOMDocument extends the standard DOM to use exceptions at all occasions of errors instead of PHP warnings or notices. They also add various custom methods and shortcuts for convenience and to simplify the usage of DOM.
- **Sabre/XML:** sabre/xml is a library that wraps and extends the XMLReader and XMLWriter classes to create a simple "xml to object/array" mapping system and design pattern. Writing and reading XML is single-pass and can therefore be fast and require low memory on large xml files.
- **FluidXML:** FluidXML is a PHP library for manipulating XML with a concise and fluent API. It leverages XPath and the fluent programming pattern to be fun and effective.

**3rd Party Libraries [  Not libxml based ]:**

- **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser:** An HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ lets you manipulate HTML in a very easy way, It Requires PHP 5+. Also Supports invalid HTML.
  It Extracts contents from HTML in a single line. The codebase is horrible and very slow in working.
- **PHP Html Parser:** HPHtmlParser is a simple, flexible, HTML parser that allows you to select tags using any CSS selector, like jQuery. The goal is to assist in the development of tools that require a quick, easy way to scrape HTML, whether it's valid or not. It is slow and takes too much CPU Power.
- **Ganon (recommended):** A universal tokenizer and HTML/XML/RSS DOM Parser. It has the Ability to manipulate elements and their attributes. It Supports invalid HTML and UTF8. It Can perform advanced CSS3-like queries on elements (like jQuery -- namespaces supported). A HTML beautifier (like HTML Tidy).  Minify CSS and Javascript. It Sort attributes, change character case, correct indentation, etc.
  Extensible. The Operations separated into smaller functions for easy overriding and
  *Fast and Easy to use.*

**Web Services:**

- If you don't feel like programming PHP, you can also use Web services. ScraperWiki's external interface allows you to extract data in the form you want for use on the web or in your own applications. You can also extract information about the state of any scraper.

I have shared all the resources, you can choose according to your taste, usefulness, etc.

Comment: Further Reading: https://newbedev.com/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with jQuery selector, you can use [ScarletsQuery](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/ScarletsQuery) for PHP

```
<pre><?php
include "ScarletsQuery.php";

// Load the HTML content and parse it
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.lipsum.com');
$dom = Scarlets\Library\MarkupLanguage::parseText($html);

// Select meta tag on the HTML header
$description = $dom->selector('head meta[name="description"]')[0];

// Get 'content' attribute value from meta tag
print_r($description->attr('content'));

$description = $dom->selector('#Content p');

// Get element array
print_r($description->view);
```

This library usually taking less than 1 second to process offline html.
It also accept invalid HTML or missing quote on tag attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library without any regex (in dom parsing and query parsing also)

https://github.com/pejman-hkh/dom-parser

This library work with all php version and I tried to work on it to have good performance. Also,  I created something like `jquery` with `pquery` name.

## Install

`composer require pejman/dom-parser`

## Usage

```php
<?php
include __dir__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$p = new \Pejman\DomParser\Parser( file_get_content('https://stackoverflow.com/tags') );

foreach( $p->find("#tags-browser",0)->children() as $tag ) {
    $link = $tag->find("a",0);
    echo $link->text()." : ";
    echo $link->href;
    echo "\n";
}
```